# How can I create a absolute url for my site using php?

Tags: php, web

Hi I am trying to crate a website using php, and the structure looks like the following:

```
-index.php
-header.php
-footer.php
-style.css
-images\{images are in this folder}
-\web\index.php
-\contact\index.php
```

The thing is i am using php's include function on all the index.php files to use the header.php and footer.php files, but the problem is that only the index.php in the root folder is showing the styles, but when i open localhost/web/index.php the page looks broke as the css and images are not found.

How can i resolve this problem.

Help please

Comment: Make sure to use absolute URL for including css, images and js.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I use the absolute path

Comment: Use full path to static files eg: instead of `images/abc.gif` use `/images/abc.gif`

Answer (score 1):

add site name in a verible like

```
$site_base_url = "http://localhost/web";
```

after that add it in front of url when u using php
like

```
echo '<link type="text/css" href="'.$site_base_url.'/style.css" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8">'
```

or like

```
echo '<img src="'.$site_base_url.'/images/file_name.jpg" />'
```

when you use functions use `global` like this

```
function find_user(){
global $site_base_url;
echo "no users found";
echo '<a href="$site_base_url">return home</a> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\header.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this structure:

- index.php
- styles/style.css
- templates/header.php
- templates/footer.php
- images/{Images go here}

I strongly suggest you read [this](http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/) tutorial. It was really helpful and easy for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

in your style.css you can use

```
background-image:url(/images/mycoolpic.png);
```

Answer (score 0):

very easy.
you have to start every path from the site root, which is simply `/`.

so, addressing style.css as a `/style.css` will let it be called from any page of the site.
same goes for all the local hyperlinks on the site - just start them from the `/` (followed by the correct path of course)